# update variable in module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the value of a private variable through a module pattern.
So what I'm saying is set $content to the value I'm passing to person.content. But this doesn't seem to work because when I do an alert  on the value it gives me an undefined error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    person.content = $('#content');
    person.getContent();

});

// Person Module
var person = ( function(){

        var $content;


        function getContent(){
                alert( 'content = '+$content.find(':first h2').text());
        }

        return { 
            content: $content,
            getContent : getContent,

        }

    }( ) );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that when you say this:

```
person.content = $('#content');
```

You're not altering the `var $content;` inside the function, you're just changing the value of the `content` property in `person`. Then, when you say this:

```
person.getContent();
```

The inner `getContent` function will be using the (uninitialized) `var $content` inside the outer function. You'll need to add a `setContent` function:

```
var person = (function(){
    var $content;
    function setContent(c) {
        $content = c;
    }
    // ...
    return {
        setContent: setContent,
        getContent: getContent
    };
}());
```

And make sure you don't leave that trailing comma in your return object, most (all?) versions of IE get upset about that.

And then, elsewhere:

```
person.setContent($('#content'));
person.getContent();
```

Depending on your target browsers and versions, you could define getter and setter functions for the properties on your returned object:

- [`__defineSetter__` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050289/setter-getter-not-working-for-number-literal/6050350#6050350)
- [`get` example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406612/javascript-accessing-parent-object-inside-function/6406695#6406695).

But using an explicit mutator function will work everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Think of values in object like pointers.

`person` is an object where the `content` property points to the `$content` value in the closure.  When you do `person.content = somethingElse` then you are setting the `content` property of the person object to point to `somethingElse` instead.

Taking the closure out of it, this illustrates the same thing:

```
var a = 'a';
var b = 'b';

var obj = { a: a }
alert(obj.a) // "a"

obj.a = b;
alert(obj.a) // "b"
alert(a) // "a"
```

Setting an objects property to a new object, never does anything to the object that used to be assign there.  It simply points to a new and different object instead.

The only way to assign this inner private variable is from inside the closure, like say in a `setContent` method.

```
return {
  getContent: function() { return $content; },
  setContent: function(val) { $content = val; }
};
```