# Is it possible to set getters on native type in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to set up a getter on a native String in JavaScript and I can't seems to get it to work. Is this even possible?

```
var message = "foo";
message.__defineGetter__("length", function() {
  return 3;
});
```

(This is for work on the Terminal)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the `length` property of a string object is read-only.

Comment: Why not just make your own method? Seems alot of hassle for little gain.

Comment: This is probably not a duplicate, but you might find it interesting/useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6050289/setter-getter-not-working-for-number-literal

Comment: That's because I send a String with ANSI character in a Node.js module, and I want it to read correct actual seen character length. So I guess it need to be a string, I could try to send a custom object with a `toString`...

Comment: _"Once a String object is created, this property is unchanging. It has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }."_ -- http://es5.github.io/#x15.5.5.1

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit odd - why would you need to set getters when the properties you are interested in are already accessible?

That said: some of them are, some of them are not, because some of them have to stay what the ECMAscript spec says they should be for JavaScript to work properly. String's `length` property is an example of an immutable property, but most `toString()` properties are perfectly mutable (with hilariously detrimental results).

So the real question is "what are you trying to do that requires you to overrule the ECMAscript spec" =)

Comment: That's because I send a String with ANSI character in a Node.js module, and I want it to read correct actual seen character length.

Comment: forgot to respond to this comment: if you use XHR to talk to node.js, by W3C decree your data must be in UTF-8 encoding. Browsers are not allowed to understand anything else for ajax requests, so if you're sending data in ANSI encoding (actually 8859-1), you'll have to turn that into UTF-8 first, then send it out as response on the node.js side.

Comment: Hey Mike, I wasn't working on browser stuff, but on Terminal issues. In the end, Node.js 0.11 fixed the ANSI encoding length issues, and I back fixed it by simply adding a façade to the Readline API so that I could add fixes in the process without seamingly changing the object. I started [extracting it in a standalone module](https://github.com/SBoudrias/readline2) this week - up to now, it've only lived inside Inquirer.js

Comment: ah, very nice. Although for future reference: based on that, your post was missing a "node.js" tag and a clarification you weren't working in the browser =P